# How to use string slicing to pull individual pieces of data for example R,P,H from a string

Tags: vb.net

we have a string with individual values such as 23.N.34.H.67 ect
 -

Comment: I edited your title to better summarize what you are wanting.

Comment: All the data's gone and this question makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Since your Mentor has suggested slicing, see if using the [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) Method is what he has in mind. I am using a lambda expression to determine the size of the array, if you do not want to use that use a List as in my other example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream telData;
    List<int> myNumbers = new List<int>();
    telData = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\inputdata.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader strmRead = new StreamReader(telData);
    string d = "";
    string tempdata;

    while ((tempdata = strmRead.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        d += tempdata;
    }
    telData.Close();


    Console.WriteLine(AverageParsedValues(d, 'H'));
    Console.WriteLine(AverageParsedValues(d, 'P'));
    Console.WriteLine(AverageParsedValues(d, 'T'));
    Console.ReadLine();

}

static double AverageParsedValues(string data, char match)
{
    int start;
    int end;
    int[] value = new int[data.Where(c => c == match).Count()];

    int index =0;
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == match)
        {
            start = data.IndexOf(':', i) + 1;
            end = data.IndexOf(':', start);
            if (int.TryParse(data.Substring(start, end - start), out temp))
            {
                value[index] = temp;
                index += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return value.Average();
}
```

---

Edit: Modified Method do away with the need for Arrays or Lists:

```
static double AverageParsedValues(string data, char match)
{
    int start;
    int end;
    int value = 0;
    double count = 0; //Double so that we return a double not an integer
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == match)
        {
            start = data.IndexOf(':', i) + 1; // Find Start of Data
            end = data.IndexOf(':', start); // Find End of Data
            if (int.TryParse(data.Substring(start, end - start), out temp))
            {
                value += temp;
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count != 0) //Check for divide by zero
        return value / count;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RyanShadesallnightCarter The reason that I used the llambda/linq was to dimesion the array. As I said earlier You need to know what size your array is when you create because redimensioned it is a very expensive operation. In this case I would probably use a List<int> like the earlier example. I guess you can just add them up in the method keep count on how many matches and then do the average. I will put up a modified Method in a bit.

Comment: @RyanShadesallnightCarter Since this is a learning experience to you please make sure you understand what the Method is doing.

Comment: @PinkFloyd That is good, I was just wanting to make sure that you understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, read all text from your text file (i'm not sure if there are newLines in your text) and then extract strings for each value. After that you will be able to parse those strings in a manner that suits you the most.

```
            string inputString = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\inputdata.txt");
            List<string> D = new List<string>();
            List<string> H = new List<string>();
            List<string> P = new List<string>();
            List<string> T = new List<string>();
            List<string> R = new List<string>();
            while (inputString.Length > 0)
            {
                int index = inputString.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'D', 'T', 'H', 'P', 'R' },1);
                string subStr = string.Empty;
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    subStr = inputString.Substring(0, index - 1);
                    inputString = inputString.Substring(index);
                }
                else
                {
                    subStr = inputString;
                    inputString = string.Empty;
                }
                switch (subStr[0])
                {
                    case 'D':
                        D.Add(subStr.Substring(1).Trim(':'));
                        break;

                    case 'T':
                        T.Add(subStr.Substring(1).Trim(':'));
                        break;

                    case 'H':
                        H.Add(subStr.Substring(1).Trim(':'));
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        P.Add(subStr.Substring(1).Trim(':'));
                        break;
                    case 'R':
                        R.Add(subStr.Substring(1).Trim(':'));
                        break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: @Nick thanks, i have never used this method i have only been using c# for about 10 class tutored hours, i have been told i need to Create a simple string/array slicing programme that would do this